# La Clojure - keyboard shortcut to go to REPL console

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, la-clojure

When I program Clojure in IntelliJ, one task I do most often is navigating back and forth between my editor and my REPL. When I am in my REPL console, I can press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to jump back to my editor. What about jumping to REPL console from my editor?

Comment: Console is displayed in the `Run` tool window which should have a number, like `4`. To open this tool window use `Alt`+`4`.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure REPL console runs in a tool window, **Run** tool window usually has number `4` associated with it, so the shortcut would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on Mac.